# Bluetooth not worknig on Macbook Pro - 2016 - 5.19.0-38-generic #39-Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, macbook

I am having problems configuring the bluetooth on my device. I tried different ways, but I cannot make this work. Could you please help me on solving this?

```
~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; uname -r; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0159]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
03:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
5.19.0-38-generic
[    0.140851] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    4.499284] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
[    4.505154] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.505175] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.505176] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.505180] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.505183] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.505188] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.555994] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    4.556000] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    4.556004] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    4.556078] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    4.556080] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    4.556126] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    4.556198] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    4.556309] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    4.556331] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    4.556333] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    4.556342] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    4.592829] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro13,1.bin failed with error -2
[    4.594573] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro13,1.txt failed with error -2
[    4.594622] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    4.894444] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4350/5 wl0: Nov 26 2015 03:48:57 version 7.35.180.133 (r602372) FWID 01-c45b39d6
[    5.173460] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.173466] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.173471] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.911096] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc18 tx timeout
[   14.911390] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: failed to write update baudrate (-110)
[   14.911423] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set baudrate
[   16.927338] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[   25.151388] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)

$sudo systemctl status bluetooth
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-04-16 23:09:42 CEST; 27min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 620 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9288)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 64ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─620 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

abr 16 23:09:41 a systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
abr 16 23:09:41 a systemd[620]: ConfigurationDirectory 'bluetooth' already exists but the mode is different. (File system: 755 ConfigurationDirectoryMode: 555)
abr 16 23:09:42 a bluetoothd[620]: Bluetooth daemon 5.65
abr 16 23:09:42 a systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
abr 16 23:09:42 a bluetoothd[620]: Starting SDP server
abr 16 23:09:42 a bluetoothd[620]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized

{}$ blueman-adapters
blueman-adapters 23.39.57 ERROR    Adapter:63 __init__  : No adapter(s) found

{}$ blueman-manager
blueman-manager 23.41.19 ERROR    Manager:147 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 23.41.19 ERROR    Manager:151 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting

{}$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available

{}$ rfkill**
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked

{}$ hciconfig -a hci0
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:14 acl:0 sco:0 commands:2 errors:0
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT

 {}$ sudo /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -n -d
bluetoothd[2961]: Bluetooth daemon 5.65
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DiscoverableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “AlwaysPairable” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “PairableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Privacy” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “JustWorksRepairing” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “TemporaryTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Name” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Class” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DeviceID” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “ReverseServiceDiscovery” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “RemoteNameRequestRetryDelay” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “AVDTP”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “AVDTP”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “AdvMon”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “BR”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “BR”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “BR”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “BR”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “BR”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “BR”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “BR”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “BR”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “BR”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “BR”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[2961]: src/main.c:main() Unable to get on D-Bus

Many thanks!
```

Comment: Providing your OS & release is almost always helpful; you've told us a kernel which is used by multiple OSes, so please tell us what OS/release you're using.

Comment: {$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.10"
VERSION="22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)"}